# Chess game design in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, chess

I built a chess game in C++. My main concern is the design. For example, in the board class it has a 2D array of pieces. This array represents the positions of the pieces, but the piece class also has a variable to store its position (used to check the validity of the move sense each piece has a different move capabilities).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "board.h"
#include "Piece.h"
#include "Presenter.h"
#include "utilities.h"
int main()
{ 

    Board board;
    Presenter presenter(&board);
    presenter.draw();

    std::cout <<endl<< "make a move by writing old then new coordinates of the piece you want to move ex: (0,1) -> (0,5)" << endl;
    int oldX, oldY, newX, newY;
    while (1)
    {
        cin >> oldX >> oldY >> newX >> newY;

        // making sure the numbers are within the board
        if (oldX > 8 || oldY > 8 || newX > 8 || newY > 8)  
        {
            cout << "one or more number is larger than 8" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        oldX--; oldY--; newX--; newY--;

        //making sure the move is valid 
        if (board.move({ oldX, oldY }, { newX, newY }) == invalid)
        {
            cout << "error: you can't move pieces from the other player " << 
             endl;
        }


        presenter.draw();


    }

}
```

**Board.cpp**

```
#include "board.h"
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
Board::Board()
{ 
    active_player = player1;
    // initializing pieces array 
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (i < 2)   pieces[i][j] = new Piece({ i, j }, player1);      //the first two rows for player1
            else if (i>5)    pieces[i][j] = new Piece({ i, j }, player2);  //the last two rows for player2
            else pieces[i][j] = new Piece({ i, j }, empty);                                  //all other rows are empty

        }
    }
}

// changes the position of the piece if its a valid move 
move_state Board::move(Coord old_pos, Coord new_pos)
{
    if (pieces[old_pos.x][old_pos.y]->get_owner() != active_player)
        return invalid; 
    else if (pieces[old_pos.x][old_pos.y]->change_position(new_pos) == valid)
    {

        std::swap(pieces[new_pos.x][new_pos.y], pieces[old_pos.x][old_pos.y]);
        active_player = (active_player == player1) ? player2 : player1;  // toggle active_player after each valid move
        return valid;
    }

    else return invalid;
}



Board::~Board()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            free(pieces[i][j]);

        }
    }
}
```

**board.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Piece.h"
#include "utilities.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Board{
    Player active_player;
    Piece *pieces[8][8];

public:
    Board();
    ~Board();
    move_state move(Coord old_pos, Coord new_pos);
    Player get_player(Coord pos)
    {
        if (pieces[pos.x][pos.y] != nullptr)   return pieces[pos.x][pos.y]->get_owner();
        else return empty;
    }
};
```

**piece.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "utilities.h"

class Piece{
 Player owner;
 Coord position;

public :
    Piece(Coord pos, Player _owner) :
        owner(_owner),
        position(pos)
    {

    }
    Player get_owner(){ return owner; }
    move_state change_position(Coord pos)
    {
        position.x = pos.x;
        position.y = pos.y;
        return valid;              // checking is not supported all moves are valid 
    }
};
```

**presenter.cpp**

```
#include "Presenter.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



Presenter::~Presenter()
{

}

void Presenter::draw()
{
    cout << "   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 ";
    cout << endl << " | ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            if (board->get_player({ i, j }) == player1) cout << "A" << "  ";
            if (board->get_player({ i, j }) == player2) cout << "B" << "  ";
            if (board->get_player({ i, j }) == empty) cout << "O" << "  ";
        }
        cout << "| "<< i+1 << endl<<" | ";
    }

}
```

**presenter.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "board.h"
class Presenter
{
    Board * board;

public:

    Presenter(Board* b){
        board = b;
    };
    void draw();

    ~Presenter();
};
```

**utilities.h**

```
#pragma once
enum Player
{
    player1,
    player2,
    empty
};


struct Coord
{
    unsigned char x;
    unsigned char y;
};
enum move_state{
    valid,
    invalid
};
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question, but the #1 advice I can give is to turn `Piece *pieces[8][8];` into `Piece pieces[8][8];`, and remove all references to operator `new`. A Piece is small, it doesn’t need dynamic allocation. If it were larger or needed dynamic allocation for another reason, you should use a `std::unique_ptr` to own each piece. Don’t use `new` unless there are no alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  It is particularly bad to put it into a header file, so please don't do that.

### Use the approprate data types

If the `Coord` values are `unsigned char`, then the loops that generate coordinates should use that instead.  For convenience, and to allow for flexibility, I'd suggest either something like this:

```
using CoordInt = unsigned char;
struct Coord
{
    CoordInt x;
    CoordInt y;
};
```

or perhaps better, make `Coord` a class and do validation of the coordinates in the constructor so that it is not possible to create invalid coordinates.

### Do better error checking

If the coordinates passed to `Board::move` are invalid (i.e. not actually on the board, the program will not work as intended due to *undefined behavior*.  Eliminate that either by doing validation of the coordinates where needed or, as per the previous suggestion, make it impossible for invalid coordinates to be constructed.

### Don't mislead the user

The user is told "make a move by writing old then new coordinates of the piece you want to move ex: (0,1) -> (0,5)" but if the user actually enters those **zero-based** coordinates, the program crashes, because what the program *actually* expects are 1-based coordinates without commas or parentheses or any other punctuation.  This leads directly to the next suggestion.

### Use standard nomenclature where it applies

In chess, the [standard algebraic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)) has been widely used for decades.  Experienced chess players will already know that notation, and it won't matter to players who aren't already familiar.  Use that notation instead of the number pairs the program currently used.

### Don't use `std::endl` if `'\n'` will do

Using `std::endl` emits a `\n` and flushes the stream.  Unless you really need the stream flushed, you can improve the performance of the code by simply emitting `'\n'` instead of using the potentially more computationally costly `std::endl`.

### Use `delete` instead of `free` in C++

The `Board` destructor uses `free` instead of `delete` which is an error.  C++ uses `new` and `delete`.  The other suggestions say you shouldn't use `free` and `delete` at all, but I understand that your intent is to have `Piece` be a base class, so this usage is appropriate once you fix this error.

### Use const where practical

The current `Piece::get_owner()` routine does not (and should not) modify the underlying object, and so it should be declared `const`:

```
Player get_owner() const { return owner; }
```

The same is true of `Presenter::draw()`.

### Reduce the use of raw pointers where practical

There is no useful thing that a `Presenter` can do with a `Board` pointer that is `nullptr`, so I'd strongly recommend using a `std::shared_ptr` instead or by having the `Board` object be a member of the `Presenter` class.

### Let the compiler create default destructor

The compiler will create a destructor by default which is essentially identical to what you've got for the `Presenter` class, so you can simply omit both the declaration and implementation from your code.

### Use consistent file names

Is it `board.h` or `Board.h`?  `Presenter.h` or `presenter.h`?  It's important to be consistent because consistency aids reader comprehension.

### Rethink the class design

If we think about a future version of this program that actually has rooks, knights, etc.  What will each piece need to determine whether a move is valid?  The current interface only passes the proposed new coordinates to `change_position`.  However, this is not enough information.  A bishop, for instance, cannot jump over other pieces, so determining a valid move will require examining all of the points between the current and proposed position as well.  This information more properly belongs to the `Board` class, so I would recommend passing a `Board` reference to the `Piece` to allow it to check for move validity.  Also, for some moves, such as castling, or capturing a pawn *en passant*, two pieces are involved and not only their positions but something about their history must be known.  For all of these reasons, I'd suggest that only the `Board` should know about positions, and to eliminate the `Coord` member from each `Piece` and that any move validity checking should pass not only the proposed `Coord` but the `Board` and current `Coord` as well.

Comment: One question - if we have a class for the Game , should it own actual players or references to players. If it owns actual ones, destroying game would free up the players, otherwise it can be reference or pointers and we will need to ensure, caller frees up the memory etc. My main point is thinking OOP principles which is preferred? Thanks!

Comment: It would depend on the context.  If it's simply done as a two-player single game, I'd probably have the board own the `Player` objects, if `Player` objects are even needed.  If it's intended to be part of a tournament, then the players would need to exist outside the context of a single game, so references would make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

@CrisLuengo's advice is valid. Past that, even if you were to keep your usage of `new`, there's a very important rule to follow: never mix C and C++ dynamic memory allocation. You've used `new` and then `free`, when you should be using `new` and then `delete`. Depending on your C libraries, compiler and system, this kind of mixing can do very bad things, potentially stack smashing, etc.

Answer (score 3):

- Consistency helps other people read, understand, and trust your code. This includes:

  - consistent whitespace (e.g. leaving an empty line after `#include`s),
  - capitalization of file names (`board.h` vs `Presenter.h`),
  - variable and type naming style (`Coord` vs `move_state`),
  - putting all function definitions in the .cpp files, instead of just some of them.
- [Don't use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- [Use `enum class` instead of plain `enum` for type-safety.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335862/673679)

---

- Variables should be declared as close to the point of use as practical (`oldX`, `oldY`, `newX`, `newY` should be inside the loop in `main`).
- Validate input thoroughly. There's no guarantee that what the user enters is an int, so we have to check that reading from `cin` worked each time. If it didn't we then have to clear the error flags on the stream, and ignore the invalid input:

  ```
  if (std::cin.fail())
  {
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }
  ```

  It would therefore be better to abstract the request for user input to a separate function with a signature like: `bool readCoord(Coord& value);`
- While we check that the input values are not too high (e.g. `oldX < 8`), we also have to check that they are not too low (if the user enters `-1`). Which leads on to...
- Use unsigned types where numbers should not be negative (e.g. for indexing into arrays).
- We could make this neater by using the `Coord` class and adding a new function to the board: `if (!(board.InBounds(old) && board.InBounds(new))) ...`.
- This line `oldX--; oldY--; newX--; newY--;` indicates that we're using 1-based indexing, but the `"...of the piece you want to move ex: (0,1) -> (0,5)"` implies 0-based indexing. Note that for 1-based indexing, we also need to check that we don't have an index of 0, even if we're using an unsigned index type.
- Nitpick: use `while (true)` instead of `while (1)`. It's a more direct statement of intent, since the latter is shorthand for `while (1 != 0)`.

---

- Don't duplicate the position inside the `Piece` class. Checking that the move is valid should be done by the board (or better by a separate `Rules` class).
- The dynamic allocation of pieces might be understandable if we were using a `nullptr` for empty squares, but without that there's no advantage over storing all the pieces by value (and all the disadvantages pointed out by Reinderien).
- It might be better to store pieces in an array of `std::optional<Piece>`, instead of having a special `empty` value in your `Player` enum for pieces that don't actually exist.
- `Presenter` should probably store a `const Board&` instead of a `Board*`. This means `Presenter` can never be given a `nullptr`, and it shows that `Presenter` never changes the board.
- `Board::get_player` can then be a const function: `Player get_player(Coord pos) const;`, since it doesn't alter the data members of the board class.
- `Presenter` can use the member initializer list to initialize the `board` variable (like the `Board` class does). Note that initializer lists specifically allow using the same name for function arguments as used for the member variable.
- Since the `Presenter` destructor does nothing, we don't need to define it ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

### Pass by reference?

Not everyone agrees, however, references ain't allowed to be nullptr. If you don't expect a nullptr, pass by reference instead of pointer.

```
Presenter presenter(board);
```

### Initialize your variables

It's always a good idea to initialize your variables, even when replacing the values with cin.
Cin leaves the value unmodified, when entering invalid data. So you have undefined behavior in your program.

So either initialize your values to an invalid value OR

### Check on input failure

```
if (!cin >> oldX)
    // Handle error
```

### Check boundaries

As indicated entering `a b c d` causes problems, entering `0 1 2 3` does as well as it will result in out of bounds access.

### Use compound initialization

If things are good they deserve a mention as well. Calling the move with pairs clearly indicates for the caller how it's grouped:

```
if (board.move({ oldX, oldY }, { newX, newY })
```

### Use standard types

```
  if (board.move({ oldX, oldY }, { newX, newY }) == invalid)
```

Why return a special value, when you only check on failure? A bool will work as well.

### std::unique_ptr

```
 if (i < 2)   pieces[i][j] = new Piece({ i, j }, player1);
```

From C++14 on, using `std::make_unique<Piece>(...)` is recommended. Storing the value in a unique_ptr indicates ownership clearly, while preventing memory-leak.

### Constants

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

8 is a really nice number, putting it in a constant allows you to give it a name.

### Check on pointers

```
 if (pieces[old_pos.x][old_pos.y]->get_owner() != active_player)
```

You haven't checked your pointer on null. Again you assume valid input.

### Const?

If you don't expect changes to an instance, make it const. If catches simple mistakes and clearly sets expectations.

```
 Player get_player(Coord pos) const
```

### Initializer list

```
Presenter(Board& b) : board(b) {
    board = b;
 };
```

### Scoped enumerations

```
enum class Player { ... };
```